# What website or online facility is the best to store examples of one's code to show a Employer?

Tags: repository

What website or online facility is the best to store examples of one's code to show  a Employer? Google code, Github etc?

Comment: What is the size of this "code"? 1 file OR 700 files with 347924 lines of code each?

Comment: Does it really matter that much?

Comment: Well my final year project could have about 1500-2500 lines of code and that would be my biggest example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github. It seems a good all rounder for the time being.